# How do I use pivot on a table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have table with data of customer, premise, cycle and phone numbers. If a customer is having more than one phone number then it should come in same row but in different column.

In database:

```
  Customer   Premise    Phone
------------------------------
C1         P1         Ph1
C1         P1         Ph2
C1         P1         Ph3
C2         P2         Ph1
```

How I want:

```
Customer   Premise    Phone   Phone1  Phone3
-----------------------------------------------
C1         P1         Ph1     Ph2     Ph3
C2         P2         Ph1     {null}  {null}
```

How to write Pivot table for this? Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to make the number of columns that are returned dynamic?  So if another phone number is added another column gets added?  If so, you'd need to dynamically assemble the SQL statement.  That will require doing a separate query to count the maximum number of phone numbers that a person has which isn't going to be terribly efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This query gives expected output:

```
select * from (
  select customer, premise, phone,
    row_number() over (partition by customer order by premise, phone) rn
  from customers)
    pivot (max(phone) phone for rn in (1, 2, 3))
```

Output:

```
CUSTOMER  PREMISE  1_PHONE  2_PHONE  3_PHONE
--------  -------  -------  -------  -------
C1        P1       Ph1      Ph2      Ph3
C2        P2       Ph1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c9d1/1)

In case you wanted dynamic number of phones please read [this article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:5312784100346298561).